# ModelForm is not rendering on browser

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a form for users to be able to create listings for an auction page however when I click the link from my index page to take me to the create page, i get redirected to the create page but on the browser, the form does not show.

INDEX.HTML

```
    <p>You can create your first auction here <a href={% url 'create_listing' %}>Add new</a></p>
```

URLS.PY

```
    path("create/", views.create_listing, name="create_listing")
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    current_bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    users_bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import context
from .forms import AuctionForm

from .models import User

def create_listing(request):
    form = AuctionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuctionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')

    context = {'form': form}  
    return render(request, 'auctions/create-listing.html', context)
```

FORMS.PY

```
from .models import Auction
from django.forms import ModelForm

class AuctionForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'current_bid']
```

CREATE-LISTING.HTML

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post" class="ui form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" class="ui button primary teal" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the form object passed correctly in the context? Can you use pdb to verify that? Is the submit button rendering properly?

Comment: Replace `def create_listing(request):` with `class create_listing(FormView)` and add `from django.views.generic.edit import FormView` also put your code in `def get(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge comes from where you have imported form modelform. below is my solution.

```
from .models import Auction
from django import forms 

class AuctionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'current_bid']
```

Comment: I tried that and re-ran the server but the browser is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the issue was I used {% block content %} instead of {% block body %}. That solved it. Thanks everyone